# Kafka Connect-standalone For Redis - No data in redis DB after topic is populated

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

New to the forum.

I have setup a Kafka connect-standalone setup for Redis. Once I start the kafka connect in standalone mode, the connector runs fine with no errors in logs. But when I produce simple test data (eg : abc) in the topic, I do not see any data or 'key' in redis.

A connection from kafka connect is observed into Redis

Only a topic was created manually before this. No key was manually created in Redis.

Command to run Kafka Connect
/path/connect-standalone v2.tempworker.properties v2.tempredis.sink.properties

```
$ cat v2.tempworker.properties
bootstrap.servers=<host IP>:<PORT>
plugin.path=/path/jcustenborder-kafka-connect-redis-0.0.2.13
offset.storage.file.filename=/path/connect.offsets

connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
errors.tolerance=all

name=v2redissink
topics=v2redistst
tasks.max=1
host=<Host IP>
port=<PORT>
password=<pwd>
dbName=0
redis.table=kafconn
redis.writer=cache
redis.type=standalone
use.record.key=true
```

---

```
$ cat v2.tempredis.sink.properties

name=v2redissink
topics=v2redistst
tasks.max=1
plugin.path=/path/jcustenborder-kafka-connect-redis-0.0.2.13/lib
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector

redis.hosts=<host IP:port>
redis.password=<pwd>
dbName=0
errors.tolerance=all
redis.table=kafconn
redis.writer=cache
redis.type=standalone
use.record.key=false

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
transforms=createKey
transforms.createKey.fields=id
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you start over with config files. Everything below `offset.storage.file.filename` in the first file needs to be moved to the second. Strings don't have schemas, so disabling that doesn't make sense. Internal converters can be removed, and aren't connector properties. Plugin path isn't a connector property either. Both shouldn't be in the second file

Comment: Also, can you provide the logs for the connector process? For example, I don't think your transform will work with plain string data since there's no "id" field in a record with no schema, causing the connector to crash and no data to get written